# filtering numbers from Python list

Tags: python, list, nltk

I am proceeding NLP to a certain data from websites. Here I have a crawled data set which is a tokenized list. I want to handle only words rather than other numbers from this list. So I've already search other similar questions and already tried those answered written but it doesn't work in my case. The picture below is the screenshot of iPython notebook that you can see some numbers on the list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePxj2.png)

I have tried those below.

```
#(1)
no_integers = [x for x in tokens if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]

#(2)    
is_integer = lambda s: s.isdigit() or (x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())
no_integers = filter(is_integer, tokens)

#(3)
def int_filter( tokens ):
for v in tokens:
    try:
        int(v)
        continue # Skip these
    except ValueError:
        yield v # Keep these

list( int_filter( tokens ))
```

I don't get what is the problem. There is not compile error. To figure out if works, I tried to compare the 'len(tokens)' of before and after. But, nothing changes.

Comment: All of these do *something*, so the `len` should change. The middle one is wrong, you want to filter for `lambda s: not s.isdigit()` so it is actually doing the inverse of what you want. The last one should work, as long as the indentation is actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all words that are integers/numbers/floats this way:

```
tokens = "I like 55 donuts with glaze".split()
no_integers = [token for token in tokens if not token.isdigit()]
print(no_integers)
```

If you wish to remove negatives and decimals:

```
tokens = "I like 55 95.5 donuts with glaze".split()
no_integers = [token for token in tokens if not all(char.isdigit() or char == '.' or char == '-' for char in token)]
print(no_integers)
token ="55"
print (all(char.isdigit() for char in token))
```

Comment: What would you prefer?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was still a generator.

Comment: yeaaa but at least 2 of OPs methods work. So, I think something is is not working.

Comment: Does he need decimal support?

Comment: I don't know... why is that relevant?

Comment: It actually works!! Thank you. but I don't get this. What were the differences between your code and this : no_integers = [x for x in tokens if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())] ??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga still the code #(1) on my post doesn't work, but the one 'nfn neil' posts does work. Are 'tokens' actually string? or list? in this case? and does it matter?

Comment: @TommyKim I'm using `tokens = "I like 55 donuts with glaze".split()` and copy-and-pasting your code exactly. It filters out the 55 and I get `['I', 'like', 'donuts', 'with', 'glaze']` It *does* work. And so does approach # 3. Approach #2 does the opposite of what you want, but it should still affect the `len`.

Comment: Tokens is a string you have split about a delimiter.  In our case, spaces.  And it does matter.  If you could mark as solution, it would help a lot.

Comment: And actually, @nfnneil you need to handle the negative number case, which passes `isdigit`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, I updated my response to support decimals.

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna try regex(regular expression)?

```
import re
x = 'I was born in the year 1997'
re.sub(r'\d','',x)
```

if there's '\d' indicating digit in x, you're gonna substitute that digit with ' ' indicating an empty string